# Create a group after a condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to split my data in two based on a gap in the dates. The problem is that in the real data, the duration of the observations is not constant. I am assigning all values of lactation to be 1, and trying to make everything after the long gap to become two.
What I am trying to do:
Identify the gap in days, if the gap is longer than 20 days, we will start counting from 1 again using group_by and row_number.
The problem here is that the lag() function is not carrying the new value after the condition.

```
    ###Code
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

#simulating the data

name<-"cow1"
milk<-rnorm(500,15,6)
date1<-seq(ymd('2012-01-01'),ymd('2012-09-06'),by='days') %>%  as_tibble()
date2<-seq(ymd('2013-01-01'),ymd('2013-09-07'),by='days') %>% as_tibble()
date<-bind_rows(date1,date2) %>% rename("day"=value)
cow1<- milk  %>% as_tibble() %>% rename("Yield"=value) %>%  mutate(cowid=name,day=date$value)  

 cow1.1 <- cow1 %>% mutate(lactation=1) %>%  
   mutate(gap = day - lag(day, default = day[1])) %>% 
   mutate(lactation=ifelse(gap>20,lag(lactation)+1,lag(lactation))) %>%
group_by(lactation) %>% mutate(dim=row_numer())
```

Sample result:

```
Row Yield  cowid    day   lactation gap
250 3.1429436 cow1 2012-09-06 1 1 days 
251 10.1427923 cow1 2013-01-01 2 117 days 
252 19.8654469 cow1 2013-01-02 1 1 days
```

Desired result:

```
Row Yield  cowid    day   lactation gap
250 3.1429436 cow1 2012-09-06 1 1 days 
251 10.1427923 cow1 2013-01-01 2 117 days 
252 19.8654469 cow1 2013-01-02 2 1 days
```

Comment: Maybe try something like `mutate(lactation=cumsum(gap>20) + 1)` to determine `lactation` - would that work for you?

Comment: Thanks, that works as a temporary fix. But as we may have more than 2 lactations it would be useful for some individuals in the dataset.

Comment: If there is a situation where this may not work, feel free to revise the question and create a sample dataset to describe further. It might also help to have a smaller example (maybe 20-30 rows of data instead of 500). Happy to help further if I can...

Comment: I just created a new dataset with 4 years and 20 rows to edit the question, and your suggestions worked just fine. I have no idea why I thought it would not work for more than two lactations before. 
Thank you so much for solving the problem, Ben

Comment: That's great to hear!